# In the Blazor WASM template project, FetchData.FetchDataAsync() works even when the host app is turned off

Tags: server, blazor-webassembly, host

After creating and launching the template project of Blazor Webassembly(7.0) in VS 2022, letting the Blazor app start in the browser, and then turning off the Blazor host server by closing the terminal, I navigated to FetchData and found the titled code still works without any problem until refreshing the browser.

Its code is as below:

```
protected async Task FetchDataAsync()
{
   forecasts =  await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
}
```

It is getting the data from the host server thru Http so I expected it to fail.

Why is that possible?

I set Kestrel.

Comment: browser cached it?

Comment: @MisterMagoo I didn't know how a browser cache works but deleted application repository in the browser and found it works as I expected.(exception thrown). can you explain in details on how to handle it? eg. configuring not to cache fetched data in the project.

Comment: `sample-data/weather.json` is a static file which can be cached.  There's no API running on the server.